# Show upload transfer time using Jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I have this upload system for a project of mine.
Everything's great, the only thing is that during the file upload, there's not progress bar of anything...so the user do not know when his file will be fully uploaded until it loads the Success page.

Here's my link :

http://mediodesign.ca/upload/docroot/

I'm using Google Chrome for browsing. When I upload a file, in the bottom left corner of the window there's the upload transfer percentage...that's the data I would like to use, but I seriously don't know how to make it work.

I would like a loading wheel (let's say "loading.gif") to appear with the upload percentage next to it. Something very simple.

Here's my index code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>


        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>File Sharing</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body id="home">
        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <h1>File Sharing</h1>
            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <input type="hidden" name="max_file_size" value="10485760" /> 

                <label for="uploadthis">Select File to Upload</label>
                <input type="file" name="uploadthis" value="" id="uploadthis">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Upload &rarr;">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my Upload success page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Upload successful</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body id="home">
        <div id="page-wrapper" class="uploadComplete">
            <h1>Upload successful</h1>
            <p class="note">Download link:</p>
            <p class="download-link"><a href="<?php echo $data['downloadLink']; ?>" class="downloadLink"><?php echo $data['shortname']; ?></a></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Anyone?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Showing a percentage of upload isn't something inclued in the HTTP procotol. AFAIK, you'll have to use either a server-side module (if you can use it) or use a Flash (or Java) external plugin to upload files.

For example, the upload process used by GMail for the attachments in mails is done by a Flash module.

Comment: I'm not sure, but the HTML5 file API might be able to do this. Don't quote me on that, though.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. I need something simple, compatible with all browsers...Sadly HTML5 is not there yet.